# Tengo que crear un nuevo array donde ponga los ingredientes en mal estado al igual que sus ingredientes próximos (ya que están contaminados también)

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, formato-condicional

Problema: El ingrediente de cierta comida está en mal estado. Hay que sacar los ingredientes próximos a éste, ya que deben estar contaminados también. La función recibe un objeto "menu" que contiene las comidas del día. "comida" es un array de ingredientes. Si "ingrediente" está en el array, devolver un array con el ingrediente y los elementos en un índice de diferencia.
Ej:

```
let menuDelDia = {
   raviolesConSalsa: ["Harina", "Sal", "-Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
   bagnaCauda: ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"],
   tallarines: ["Harina", "Pollo", "Aceite", "Huevos", "Tomates", "Cebolla"]
}
```

```
ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Peceto") devuelve => ["Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"];

ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "tallarines", "Aceite") devuelve => ["Pollo", "Aceite", "Huevos"];
```

En caso de no encontrarse el ingrediente en la comida, devolver "El menú está perfecto".

*NOTA*: No utilizar el método "**includes**".

Tu código:
Añado array vacío que contiene ingredientes en mal estado

```js
function ingredienteEnMalEstado(menu, comida, ingrediente) {
 
        
  ingrediente1 = [];
    
//Creo un for para encontrar los ingredientes y sus ingredientes próximos que también están contaminados.
    
  for(var i = 0; i < comida.length; i++){
    
// Si ingrediente se encuentra en el primer elemento de comida entonces el .push lo hago sobre comida[0] y comida[1] que serían los ingredientes en mal estado.

    if(comida[0] === ingrediente){
      ingrediente1.push(comida[0], comida[1]);
        
//Acá accedería al último y penúltimo elemento del array comida y lo agrego a la lista de elementos en mal estado.
    }else 
      if(comida[comida.length-1] === ingrediente){
        ingrediente1.push(comida[comida.length-1],
        comida[comida.length-2]);
      
// En caso que Ingrediente se encuentre en medio del array, agrego el ingrediente y los elementos próximos a este.
 
      }else 
        if(comida[i] === ingrediente){
          ingrediente1.push(comida[i], comida[i-1], comida[i+1]);
        }else if(comida[i] !== ingrediente){
      
      //en caso que no esté ingrediente retorno el siguiente mensaje.
          return 'El menú está perfecto'}
      }
      return ingrediente1;
    };
```

Comment: Puedes incluir la variable comida y ingrediente para ver el formato.

Comment: Ahí le agregué las 2 variables

Comment: Está todo el código comentado...

Comment: Si sin querer puse un tilde y me faltó cerrarlo

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta e indicar el error o lo que pretendes, no queda claro, que es el parámetro menu, no lo utilizas dentro de la función.

Comment: Menú es un array de comida, comida es un array de ingredientes. El error es que no sé si está bien la sintaxis, la idea del ejemplo es pasar un ingrediente en mal estado y sus próximos como mal estado y ubicarlos en un array aparte.

Comment: Si te entiendo bien, básicamente lo que haces es una comparación entre el array de comida y el array de ingredientes? y si coinciden ya haces el push? @Raul

Comment: Si, en caso que ingrediente no se encuentre en comida devuelvo el mensaje 'El menú está perfecto'

Comment: Si estás recibiendo un parámetro llamado comida, no tiene sentido crear una variable local con el mismo nombre dentro de la función

Comment: Si tienes razón ahí quité las variables

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar en el título de la pregunta _cuál es exactamente el problema_? Si otros usuarios llegan a tener tu mismo problema, les va a ser muy difícil encontrar esta pregunta si lleva el título "qué estoy haciendo mal".

Comment: Tenes razón, ya modifique el título. Gracias por tu comentario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo he entendido bien, lo que necesitas es lo siguiente:

```js
function ingredienteEnMalEstado(comida, ingredientes){
  ingrediente1 = [];
  for(var i=0; i < comida.length; i++){
    for(var y=0; y<ingredientes.length; y++){
      if(comida[i] === ingredientes[y]){
        ingrediente1.push(comida[i], comida[i-1], comida[i+1]);
      }
    }
  }
  if (ingrediente1.length === 0){
    return 'El menú está perfecto';
  }
  else{
    return ingrediente1;
  }
}

let comida = ['tallarines','ravioles', 'Bagnacauda'];
let ingredientes = ['huevos', 'tomate', 'cebolla', 'ajo', 'anchoas', 'aceite'];
var resultado = ingredienteEnMalEstado(comida, ingredientes);
if(Array.isArray(resultado)){
  for (var i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){
    if(resultado[i] === undefined){
      resultado.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(resultado)
  for (var y = resultado.length - 1; y>=0; y--){
    if (resultado.indexOf(resultado[y]) !== y)
      resultado.splice(y, 1);
  }
}

console.log(resultado);
```

Básicamente lo que te faltaba era iterar sobre el array **ingredientes** también, porque necesitas comparar cada índice de ambos array, por eso he puesto otro for.

Por otro lado tenías muchos if else que no son necesarios. Con uno es suficiente porque al usar los índices (i,y) ya itera por todos los elementos de ambos array.

Luego comprueba si se ha añadido algún ingrediente en mal estado al array de **ingrediente1** y sino devuelve que esta perfecto.
Por fuera de la función he hecho dos for que eliminan si se ha añadido algún elemento **undefined** porque por ejemplo al hacer en la función `comida[i-1]` puede que no haya nada en esa posición. El otro for es por si se añaden elementos repetidos en el array debido a las iteraciones. Seguro esta última parte se puede optimizar.

Espero haberte ayudado y cualquier duda me comentas.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo!, si como dices tengo muchos else if repetidos y me faltó iterar sobre el array ingredientes también. Estaba estancando en este ejercicio y pesé a que busqué por internet no encontraba solución. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada!! Me alegra haberte ayudado. :) @Raul

Answer (score 0):

Te hice una **demo** para que la pruebes. No tuve en cuenta si la comida no existe, pero puedo añadirlo si quieres. Lo he hecho de la forma más sencilla posible, para que puedas llegar a entenderlo. De todas formas, si tienes cualquier duda puedes consultármela.

Devuelve justo el segundo resultado del ejemplo que pusistes, donde el ingrediente es '*Aceite*' y la comida '*tallarines*'.

```js
ingredienteEnMalEstado('menuDelDia', 'Aceite', 'tallarines');

function ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, ingrediente, comida) {
        
   var menuDelDia = {
   raviolesConSalsa: ["Harina", "Sal", "Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
   bagnaCauda: ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"],
   tallarines: ["Harina", "Pollo", "Aceite", "Huevos", "Tomates", "Cebolla"]
  }

  let malEstado = [];
  
  let hayIngrediente = false;
  
  let claves = Object.keys(menuDelDia);
  
  for(let i=0; i< claves.length; i++){
    let clave = claves[i];
    if (comida === claves[i]){
          for (let j=0; j<menuDelDia[clave].length; j++){
            if (ingrediente === menuDelDia[clave][j]){
              malEstado.push(menuDelDia[clave][j], menuDelDia[clave][j+1], menuDelDia[clave][j-1]);
              hayIngrediente = true;
            }
      
    
          }
    }

  }
      if (hayIngrediente === true) {
        console.log(malEstado);
      } else {
        console.log("El menú está perfecto.");
      }
};
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Como comenté antes, si necesitas que añada la funcionalidad de comprobación de **si la comida no existe**, házmelo saber. Un saludo.